# Getting error Xamarin.android.JNIenv requires a buisness licence or higher

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

Hi I am trying to work with xamarin. So I have created an account on xamarin and downloaded the xamrin from there. After installation i am not able to run the android apps on visual studio 2013.

It is giving error asking to purchase a buisness licence.

Why am I getting this thing I am not able to understand as I have registered for a free trial.

Secondly i am also not able to see any computer attached to my account can this be the problem if yes can anyone suggest how I can overcoe this.

I went through the xamarin forums but was not able to find where I couldpost my question and get help.

Comment: Have you logged into your Xamarin account? You can do that from within the "Tools -> Xamarin"  menu.

Comment: Yes I have logged in. I can see for android and ios status as STARTER. But when I visit my account it is not showing any computer attached.